# Apache2 Web server is running but not serving after migrating to ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apache2, php7

I appreciate a little help; I spent couple of days trying to rectify this issue.

Basically My web server runs normally only after de-activating php7.2.

First I attempt to de-activate all PHP versions

```
sudo a2dismod php7.2
sudo a2dismod php5
sudo a2dismod php7.0
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

No errors and the web server works and serves Wordpress.
Now lets enable php7.2

```
sudo a2enmod php7.2
sudo systemctl restart apache2
sudo a2query -m php7.2
>php7.2 (enabled by site administrator)
```

Now web server doesnt work. Can not serve wordpress. No errors shown

```
 sudo systemctl status apache2
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2020-01-04 20:13:26 AEDT; 2min 13s ago
  Process: 24208 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 9759 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 24213 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 24218 (apache2)
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           ├─24218 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           └─24219 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Jan 04 20:13:25 UBSERVER systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jan 04 20:13:26 UBSERVER apachectl[24213]: [Sat Jan 04 20:13:26.025305 2020] [alias:warn] [pid 24216] AH00671: The Alias directive in /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf at line 3 will probably nev
Jan 04 20:13:26 UBSERVER systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Some errors from /var/log/apache2/error.log

```
/usr/sbin/apache2: Relink `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_systemd.so.2' with `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1' for IFUNC symbol `clock_gettime'
[Sat Jan 04 20:16:39.820165 2020] [core:notice] [pid 24218] AH00051: child pid 25534 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
/usr/sbin/apache2: Relink `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_systemd.so.2' with `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1' for IFUNC symbol `clock_gettime'
/usr/sbin/apache2: Relink `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_systemd.so.2' with `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1' for IFUNC symbol `clock_gettime'
/usr/sbin/apache2: Relink `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_systemd.so.2' with `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1' for IFUNC symbol `clock_gettime'
/usr/sbin/apache2: Relink `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_systemd.so.2' with `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1' for IFUNC symbol `clock_gettime'
[Sat Jan 04 20:16:40.824374 2020] [core:notice] [pid 24218] AH00051: child pid 25536 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sat Jan 04 20:16:40.824452 2020] [core:notice] [pid 24218] AH00051: child pid 25537 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
/usr/sbin/apache2: Relink `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_systemd.so.2' with `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1' for IFUNC symbol `clock_gettime'
/usr/sbin/apache2: Relink `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_systemd.so.2' with `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1' for IFUNC symbol `clock_gettime'
/usr/sbin/apache2: Relink `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_systemd.so.2' with `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1' for IFUNC symbol `clock_gettime'
/usr/sbin/apache2: Relink `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_systemd.so.2' with `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1' for IFUNC symbol `clock_gettime'
/usr/sbin/apache2: Relink `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_systemd.so.2' with `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1' for IFUNC symbol `clock_gettime'
/usr/sbin/apache2: Relink `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_systemd.so.2' with `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1' for IFUNC symbol `clock_gettime'
/usr/sbin/apache2: Relink `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_systemd.so.2' with `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1' for IFUNC symbol `clock_gettime'
/usr/sbin/apache2: Relink `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_systemd.so.2' with `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1' for IFUNC symbol `clock_gettime'
[Sat Jan 04 20:16:41.032015 2020] [core:notice] [pid 24218] AH00051: child pid 25540 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sat Jan 04 20:16:41.032106 2020] [core:notice] [pid 24218] AH00051: child pid 25541 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sat Jan 04 20:16:41.032134 2020] [core:notice] [pid 24218] AH00051: child pid 25542 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sat Jan 04 20:16:41.032156 2020] [core:notice] [pid 24218] AH00051: child pid 25545 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
/usr/sbin/apache2: Relink `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_systemd.so.2' with `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1' for IFUNC symbol `clock_gettime'
[Sat Jan 04 20:16:41.376926 2020] [core:notice] [pid 24218] AH00051: child pid 25554 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sat Jan 04 20:16:41.376971 2020] [core:notice] [pid 24218] AH00051: child pid 25555 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sat Jan 04 20:16:41.376990 2020] [core:notice] [pid 24218] AH00051: child pid 25556 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sat Jan 04 20:16:41.377008 2020] [core:notice] [pid 24218] AH00051: child pid 25557 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sat Jan 04 20:16:41.377026 2020] [core:notice] [pid 24218] AH00051: child pid 25560 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sat Jan 04 20:16:41.377043 2020] [core:notice] [pid 24218] AH00051: child pid 25563 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sat Jan 04 20:16:41.377060 2020] [core:notice] [pid 24218] AH00051: child pid 25567 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sat Jan 04 20:16:41.377103 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 24218] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Jan 04 20:17:31.165424 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 25660] AH01906: ub-server.com:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Sat Jan 04 20:17:31.165441 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 25660] AH01909: ub-server.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue:
sudo nano /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
uncommend the gd2 extension: extension=gd2
remove, purge and install php7.2-gd
load the module: phpenmod -v 7.2 php7.2-gd
Restart appache2
sudo systemctl restart apache2